# Gantt Chart in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, dll, charts

i'm trying to create a gantt chart in windows form c#, i've tried to find any library but no luck, i've found ms chart control, but i don't know how to use it

there is sample from msdn, but when i put it on my code, it's not showing any graph

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
...

// Populate series data
DateTime    currentData = DateTime.Now.Date;
chart1.Series["Tasks"].Points.AddXY(1, currentData, currentData.AddDays(5));
chart1.Series["Tasks"].Points.AddXY(2, currentData.AddDays(5), currentData.AddDays(7));
chart1.Series["Tasks"].Points.AddXY(3, currentData.AddDays(7),         currentData.AddDays(10));
chart1.Series["Tasks"].Points.AddXY(1, currentData.AddDays(10), currentData.AddDays(15));
chart1.Series["Tasks"].Points.AddXY(4, currentData.AddDays(15), currentData.AddDays(20));
chart1.Series["Tasks"].Points.AddXY(2, currentData.AddDays(20), currentData.AddDays(27));

chart1.Series["Progress"].Points.AddXY(1, currentData, currentData.AddDays(5));
chart1.Series["Progress"].Points.AddXY(2, currentData.AddDays(5), currentData.AddDays(7));
chart1.Series["Progress"].Points.AddXY(3, currentData.AddDays(7), currentData.AddDays(10));
chart1.Series["Progress"].Points.AddXY(1, currentData.AddDays(10), currentData.AddDays(13));
```

is there any library that i can use? or if it's not is there any tutorial to create it??

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in WPF

http://wpfgantt.codeplex.com/

Comment: is there any documentation? i've tried it, but when i tried to zoom it threw an exception, and when i add ontimelineChanged it's just not working,

Comment: thats just what I found don't know much about it